# How to remove a cascade on delete from a particular relationship in EF5

Tags: entity-framework

I've got a code first model in EF5 (I think - the latest version in VS2012) and I'm getting an error on initialisation of database: -

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '...' on table '...' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

I want to keep the default convention of having on delete cascade, but remove it for that particular relationship.  I've tried overriding OnModelCreating using modelbuilder.Entity.HasMany.HasForeignKey.WillCascadeOnDelete(False), but when I do that, I get an error that the foreign key already exists.

Comment: The exact procedure to remove a foreign key that is specific to a relationship is described in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884940/setting-table-level-willcascadeondelete-not-available it looks like you've left out HasRequired()